# i want to print arabic string value + num value in the same line

Tags: python-3.11

i updatae in databse the variable
self.se_var.get() = 1
se_value = "ع د/ب ج/7" + "/" + (self.se_var.get())
print(se_value)
the result I get is: ع د/ب ج/7/1
but i need the result like that: ع د/ب ج/7 and "/" and "1" from left to right
can any one help me?

i try:
i updatae in databse the variable
self.se_var.get() = 1
se_value = "ع د/ب ج/7" + "/" + (self.se_var.get())
print(se_value)
the result I get is: ع د/ب ج/7/1
but I need the result like that: ع د/ب ج/7 and "/" and "1" from left to right
can any one help me?
in python pls.